# "Более правильно" или "более правильнее" - как верно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сравнительная-степень

Как правильно сказать:

*«нужно питаться более правильно» или «нужно питаться более правильнее»?*

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего будет сказать:

***Нужно питаться правильнее.***

*Более правильно* допустимо, но громоздко — лучше обойтись одним словом. Говорить *более правильн**ее*** однозначно неправильно: либо просто *сравнительная степень прилагательного,* оканчивающаяся на *-ее,* либо *более + наречие.*